# Convertir una cadena de texto en formato IP y realizar un +1 en cada ciclo en C#

Tags: c#

Se esta realizando una búsqueda de todas las IP en una red local, lo que trato de hacer es que mi función tome la IP principal que aparece en un Label por ejemplo: 192.168.1.0 haga el recorrido con el +1 del bucle.

En mi código puse directamente la red y diciendo que el ultimo numero le sume 1 en cada ciclo de búsqueda, pero ¿cómo le haría si lo tomo directamente de un Label o una caja de texto?

```
string ip = string.Format("192.168.10.{0}", i);
```

Comment: tomas que cosa de un label? porque si tomas los mismo que nos muestras en el string.format donde se usa el {0} entonces aplica de la misma forma

Comment: La IP actual de mi red, que en mi caso seria 192.168.10.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta claro que vas a tener que parsear los valores separandolos por el punto

```
string[] partes = lblIp.Text.Split('.');
int ultimo_nro = int.Parse(partes[3]);

for(int i = ultimo_nro; ...; i++)
{
  string ip = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", partes[0], partes[1], partes[2], i);
  lista.Add(ip);
}
```

la idea es rearmar la ip con las diferentes partes que separas

Comment: Muchas gracias @Leandro Tuttini entendi muy bien el punto y pude lograrlo con solo esta parte del  codigo: 

string[] partes = lblIp.Text.Split('.');
 int ultimo_nro = int.Parse(partes[3]);
  string ip = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", partes[0], partes[1], partes[2], i);

Answer (score 3):

Extrae el último valor de la IP:

```
String ip = "192.168.0.42";
var ultimo_valor = ip.Split('.').Last();
```

Después puedes convertirlo a número de la manera que creas conveniente:

```
var valor = int.Parse(ultimo_valor);
```

Y ya lo puedes usar:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("192.168.0.{0}", valor * 3));
```

Comment: por curiosidad, como harias cuando llegue a 255, los convencionales harian un if, capaz usas una regla binaria para cambiarlo

Comment: porque valor * 3?

Comment: @JackNavaRow ese es un problema para quien hizo la pregunta.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Por qué no? Es un código tan solo ilustrativo, para que se vea que es un valor numérico evito el operador `+` que puede confundirse con un concatenado, usando el operador `*` se ve que es un número.

Comment: Ok, pero siembra mas dudas que certezas.. y porque no usar directamente interpolacion de variables?

Comment: @gbianchi No usé interpolación: (`$"192.168.0.{valor * 3}"`) porque quien hizo la pregunta tampoco la usó.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es verdad disculpa, gracias por tomar el tiempo en ayudarme. Solo que si me confundio un poco su respuesta y yo apenas estoy aprendiendo a programar